# Could not find worklightconsole.war

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm trying to create and deploy a MobileFirst Platform 6.3 application using the MobileFirst CLI. While running the server, I got the following error:

> BUILD FAILED
>   /Applications/IBM/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml:361:
>   Could not find worklightconsole.war. The element  inside
>    is missing an attribute 'warFile'.

Steps Followed:

1. Installed Worklight CLI
2. Created server
3. Created project
4. Created adapter
5. Created hybrid app with iOS and Android environment.
6. Started the server and got this error

Also when I opened the file mentioned in the error, I found that the `<console>` tag is empty.
When I try to open the Worklight console in browser, it says "Context Root Not Found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in the provided CLI. [Please re-download](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_cli_installer_6.3.0.zip).

With the above updated version, the following works:

```
mfp create testproj
cd testproj
mfp start
```